# Swift working with \n \r \t characters

Tags: swift

I have a .txt file including text like balboa\n\rblabla\n
when i parse the text and print it, i want to show new line instead of \n, it still prints \n, \r characters to the console. I'm new to swift, what is the problem here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As rmmaddy said, don't put the escape sequences in your file. Use the symbols they actually represent.

And here's why: the escape sequences such as `\n` do not actually exist in files where the new lines are. Those escape sequences are a way for you to input (into the source code) characters that are otherwise inexpressible. As soon as that string is created, those escape sequences are substituted for their actual meanings.

For example suppose we have this string:

```
let s = "a\nb"
```

It looks like 4 characters (`a`, `\`, `n`, `b`), right? Well take a look at this:

```
print(s.characters.count) // 3
```

The `String` is actually composed of 3 characters (`a`, a newline character, and `b`). The `\n` escape sequence existed solely for you to communicate to the compiler "I want a new line character here", rather that representing it by actually having to type a new line. As soon as the compiler saw it, it replaced it with the new line character represents.

Suppose you had a simple program that took a `String` literal (a string defined directly in your source code) and wrote it into a file. Imagine the process by which this occurs as a pipeline, roughly like so:

```
String literal ---> compiler ---> app binary ---> running app instance in RAM ---> file.txt
```

Of all those "pipes" (`--->`), only one of them uses (`\n`): the one between the source and the compiler. Everything after that now deals with the binary representation of a newline (e.g. `0x0A` in ASCII).